# TF400997: Configuring Scheduled backup with TFS 2013

Tags: sql, tfs, backup

I am getting TF400997 when I am trying to configure TFS Scheduled backup using TFS Admin console. Here is my setup:

SQL Server name: Machine1
SQL Server service running under: sqlserverservice@domain.com (which is a domain user and local admin on Machine1 and Machine2)
SQL Server agent service running under: sqlserverservice@domain.com

TFS server name: Machine2
TFS service running under: tfsservice@domain.com (local admin on Machine2 and Machine1)
Network backup path: \Machine2\Backup (gave full permission to sqlserverservice@domain.com on Backup folder)

This is what I am getting while verifying the settings and it does not allow me to setup scheduled backup:
[image: Here is what I am getting:]

Google this already and it looks like my setup should work, Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backup is executed by TFS Job Service: check also TFS user's permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Guilio, I made tfsservice as local admin on sql server (TFS backup job service is running with tfsservice account) but it made no difference, same error.

Comment: What about the share permissions (both share and folder): I just noticed that the error is about the SQL user accessing the network share

Comment: tfsservice and sqlservice both have full permission on the folder and share but still the same, I might considering doing setting up scheduled backup manually using maintenance plan as described in admin guide

Comment: In the log file you may see more details on the error. The doc at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh561429.aspx says that you have to consider also the user at the console creating the backup.

Comment: If you're not an administrator for TFS, a member of the SQL Server System Administrators group, and (if your deployment uses SharePoint Products) a member of the Farm Administrators group, get those permissions now.

In addition, the service account for TFS (TFSService) must have SQL Server Perform Back Up and Create Maintenance Plan permissions set to Allow on each instance of SQL Server that hosts the databases that you want to back up, and Full Control on the network share, folder, or storage device where the backups will be kept.

Comment: Thanks for the help Guilio, I could not able to try the suggestion you gave me due to time constraint. I follow the manual setup path and it pretty much the same what you suggested so I will mark your help as "answered" thanks once again.

Answer (score 12):

Please try this one:

- configure your SQL Account to run under `domain\tfsservice` instead of `tfsservice@domain.com`
- configure your TFSBackup

Comment: I also had this issue and Igors suggestion fixed it.  I checked services.msc and saw that both the SQL Server and SQL Server Agent services on my TFS server were running as tfsadmin@domain.com instead of domain\tfsadmin.  I changed both the logins to domain\tfsadmin and the error went away and I was able to successfully reconfigure my backups. Thanks Igor!

Comment: After trying a lot of things, this was the thing that was giving problems. when you select a domain user in windows to be used as the one running the service, windows automaticallu sets the username@domain.local (e.g. tfsservice@development.local) you need to manually change the Account name to domain\username ( e.g. development\tfsservice).

Answer (score 1):

The network share has to have computer (machine) based security rights. Here are the steps you have to do:

- Open the properties of the shared folder on target machine.
- Open the "Security" tab
- Click on "Edit" button under the "Group or user names" frame. This will open the folder permissions window
- Click "Add" on the "Permissions for ..." window. This will open the user/group selection window
- Click "Object Types" button on the selection window. This will open the "Object Types" window
- Select "Computers" on the "Object Types" window. Click on "Ok". This will close the "Object Types" window
- Enter the target machine name into the object name frame. You can use the "Check Names" button to validate the name or use the "Advanced" button to select the computer from the domain objects list. Click on "Ok" and close the user/group selection window
- Select the recently added computer object on the permissions window and give it the required permissions.
- Close the remaining windows by clicking "Ok"

and voila!

The only tip I could mention is that you shouldn't use a subfolder from another share. It's possible but most probably you would end up dealing with mixed permissions.

PS: The SQL Service on TFS should be either in "Network Service" or "SYSTEM" context. Local account service logons won't gain access to the network share with these steps.

Answer (score 0):

go to services and make this service SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) log on as administrator